# Retaining Header name while importing flat file into sql

Tags: sql-server, ssms, csv-import

I am trying to import a flat file into sql. My headers look like this in notepad

SCSItem.[Item],SCSItem.[PhaseOutItemType]

But when I import this into sql using "Import Data" it removes the period and the bracket. This is what it looks like after the import

[image]

Is there a way to retain the header info ?

Comment: I presume that you're using Microsoft SQL Server.  Can you tag that, or whichever RDBMS and version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Both periods `.` and square brackets `[]` are [reserved syntax in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you want the field name to be:

> SCSItem.[Item]

Then you need to use the other, ANSI Standard, [identifier quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which is `"`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE has_brackets
 ("SCSItem.[Item]" nvarchar(100)
 ,"SCSItem.[PhaseOutItemType]" nvarchar(100)
 );
```

Comment: While this answers the question, I think putting these characters into identifiers is bad practice.  I have to recommend renaming the field as a better idea.